# Blender freezing when pressing loose parts

Tags: 3d-view, edit-mode

I'm losing hope here. I have a complex architectural OBJ file which I need to separate in loose parts. However, every time I press separate loose parts the software freezes. Object has:

- Vertices 1,733,978
- Edges 3,541,057
- Faces 1,848,917
- Triangles 3,229,066

My laptop is:

- Processor:    12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-12800H   2.40 GHz
- Installed RAM:    64.0 GB (63.7 GB usable)
- System type:  64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

Comment: Hello ! Judging by the vertices / triangles ratio I thinker either your base object has millions of parts which will make Blender freeze for a long time, or the mesh is not welded. In edit mode select everything and right click > Merge Vertices > By distance